# "Your vote has been recorded and it affects this post’s ranking " - Stack Overflow's new message about downvoting a question

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, voting, down-votes

> Thanks for your vote! Your vote has been recorded and it affects this post’s ranking. Since this post’s score is below -1, your vote will not be displayed.
>   Please consider adding a comment if you think this post can be improved.

[image]

when I am trying to put a downvote on a `Question` Stack Overflow. can some one please explain this new rules? I have seen this message from last two days.